# InfluxDB sum all latest value based on tag

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I have a database with some DHCP metrics

Tags and examples:

- `Name`, *e.g. `Server network`*
- `ScopeId`, *e.g. `10.10.10.0`*
- `Free`, *e.g. `1`*
- `InUse`, *e.g. `99`*
- `Reserved`, *e.g. `10`*
- `Percentage in use`, *e.g. `99%`*

The `ScopeId` is **unique** and the `Name` is **not unique**.

I'm trying to achieve some panels in **Grafana** that displays statistics for our DHCP metrics but run into a problem when ***scope names*** are *not unique*.

Example:

I want to know how many IP addresses are free in this scope based on a name. My query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT last(Free) FROM "Scope_Stats" WHERE ("Name" = 'Server network') group by ScopeId
```

which returns:

```sh
name: Scope_Stats
tags: ScopeId=10.10.10.0
time                Free
----                ----
1584045598125616200 356

name: Scope_Stats
tags: ScopeId=10.10.20.0
time                Free
----                ----
1584045579287037900 219
```

How can I sum up all of the **Free** values into one? I can't figure it out since I only want the last value for each of the ScopeId's.

Example 2:

I don't have any code, but how would I structure a query to get **the sum of** `Free`, `InUse` and `Reserved` addresses to get total addresses?

Comment: I suggest using [InfluxQL Continuous Queries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/continuous_queries/#substituting-for-nested-functions) for complicated queries